# Use parameter in list | Flutter/Dart

Tags: list, flutter, dart, variables, parameters

I´m new to flutter and got a question that makes me crazy for 2 days :)
I want to use a parameter(name1) in a list, but can´t figure out what went wrong:

```
  List<Widget> player = [Text(name1)];
  String name1 = 'Max';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: player[0],
    );
  }
}
```

Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read 'name1'

This is a simplified version, but includes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a just initialized variable to initialize another variable. You can call the variable inside a method. For example if is a StatefulWidget, you can fill the list inside the initState method.

```
  List<Widget> player = [];
  String name1 = 'Max';
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    player.add(Text(name1));
    super.initState();
  }
```

Or you can initialize the list with all the widgets already:

```
List<Widget> player = [Text('name1'),Text('name2')];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That helps me with understanding the problem. Maybe you know a solution to a problem that comes along with your answer: 

I have a stless Wigdet in a list and want to pass data to it.

 List <Widget> player = [ custom_widget(name: name1 ) ];

name is the parameter I use in the custom_widget, name1 is the value that is passed.

Since I can´t do it as I planed to do, maybe you know another way of doing it?

Comment: Well, you can do this inside a method, like i said, just create a method to initialize the list inside it, then call where you want. Maybe if you show more code and where is the error we can find a solution for it.

Comment: Hey, I found a solution with initState. Without your answer I´d still sit here bumping my head against the wall. Thanks so much!